# ExpressJS - Common response middleware

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I want to set-up middleware such that, each middleware 'terminates' into one common middleware that sets up the response object to be sent. I need this because, I have to add some custom headers and response messages (including i18n) before I do a `res.status(code).send(resp)`.

Here is the structure I have in mind.

```
function appSeup() {
    const app = express()
    //  API token check
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        let options = {
            requestId: req.get('...'),
            token: req.get('...')
        }
        let c = auth.authenticate(options)
        if (c.check) {
            // Go to common response object middleware with c
        } else {
            // Go to common response object middleware with c
        }
    })
    // End-points
    app.post('/books', async (req, res, next) => {
        let c = createBookService(req)
        // Go to common response object middleware with c
    })
    //
    app.post('/book/:bookId', async (req, res, next) => {
        let c = getBookService(req)
        // Go to common response object middleware with c
    })
    // 404 - Not found
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        let c = mw.notfound(req)
        // Go to common response object middleware with c
    })
    // Common response object
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        // Build common response object with custom headers and response messsages.
        // How do I pass the c created by any of the above?
    })
    return app
}
```

Comment: Imo, it would be better to place your "common response" logic as method in `res`, which you can define in that first mw, then in each route you can do `res.commonResponse({vals:2,pass:''})`, happy to add as answer, is just different then using a "last" middleware

Comment: That is a good idea! Please feel free to add as an answer. It would be really great if you can also elaborate, in your answer, how 'last' middleware is not a tenable choice.

Comment: in express, to pass data from one middleware to next middleware, you can add it into the request, example: req.myDataToReturn = c; next() .... and finally, in the common middleware you can access this data by res.send(req.myDataToReturn)